# jQuery ui size effect is not resizing to the specified width/height

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery UI v1.8.17 (testing in FF 10.0 on Ubuntu)

- **Update**: I've put my script and html on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JhqrX/3/

We are trying to fit large data tables into a fixed width design, and have opted for initially displaying a scaled down version of the table which can be clicked on to view at 100%.

I have found the jQuery UI size effect method, and it has a nice effect where it also scales everything inside the tables (cells, padding, text/font).

However, one problem is that we have to specify the new height and width (it would be great if we could just pass a width and it maintained aspect ratios) - but the other, much larger, problem is that it is not actually sizing to the specified dimensions.

For example - I have a table that is 502x60 and want that to fit into 300x36. Passing this height and width as parameters into the size method gets me a table that is about 354x40. When I reset to 502px in a subsequent size request, it actually is set to about 492px. Subsequent resizing seems to bounce between a width of 334 (when I want 300) and 492 (when I want 502).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* create a selector for all tables over the width limit */
    $.expr[':'].wideTable = function(obj) {
        return $(obj).width() > 300;
    }

    /* create an array of width table dimensions */
    var wideTableWidths = [];
    $('table:wideTable').each(function() {
        wideTableWidths[$(this).attr('id')] = {
            width: $(this).width(),
            height: $(this).height(),
            ratio: $(this).height() / $(this).width(),
            scaled: false,
        };
    });

    /* set up the click event to resize the tables */
    $('table:wideTable').click(function() {
        if (wideTableWidths[$(this).attr('id')].scaled) {
            /* if the table is currently scaled, we can reset to original height and width as stored */
            $(this).effect("size", {to: {width: wideTableWidths[$(this).attr('id')].width, height: wideTableWidths[$(this).attr('id')].height} }, 0);
            wideTableWidths[$(this).attr('id')].scaled = false;
        } else {
            /* if the table requires scaling, we know we want a width of 300px and the height should be set to match the original aspect ratio */
            $(this).effect("size", {to: {width: 300, height: 300 * wideTableWidths[$(this).attr('id')].ratio} }, 0);
            wideTableWidths[$(this).attr('id')].scaled = true;
        }
    });

    /* initialise the page so that all wide tables are scaled to fit */
    $('table:wideTable').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the jsFiddle you have provided, I found the solution to the problem.

The initial ratio calculation doesn't take into account the `padding` and `border` values of `table td`.
You need to subtract these from the `height` and `width`.

This [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhqrX/9/) demonstrates the solution.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks - I was heading along the same line myself, but didn't feel right snatching the answer since you'd helped me along with your comments this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is related, but what is your doc type? I had issues with height/width calculations and not having a doctype defined with jqueryui. Try `<!DOCTYPE html>` if you dont already have one.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have not set the `scale` argument within your `.effect` call.

The default value for `scale` is `both` which means that the resize affects both border and padding values.

In obtaining your original height and width values, you have used:

```
width: $(this).width()
height: $(this).height()
```

which return the content width of the elements (ie, not including the border, padding, or margin).

You can try using the `.outerWidth()` and `.outerHeight()` methods which include the border and padding, or specify `scale: 'content'` in your call to the `.effect` method. For example:

```
$(this).effect("size", {to: {width: 300, height: 300 * wideTableWidths[$(this).attr('id')].ratio, scale: 'content'} }, 0);
```

Comment: outerWidth and outerHeight end up with the table being bigger than it should be... setting the scale parameter to 'content' doesn't really change anything

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post. I would keep the `.width()` and `.height` calls and specify the `scale: 'content'` parameter.
That way, the original dimensions are for content, and the `size` effect only affects content.

Comment: hmmm.. still doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: The `size` effect appears to be taking `padding` into consideration no matter what option you set. I've created [the following jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVRN4/1/) to demonstrate. If you have a play with the `padding` value of the `#target` selector in CSS, you can see how it affects the `size` effect.

Comment: Sorry - the jsFiddle didn't save properly - here's the correct link - [http://jsfiddle.net/GPpJh/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/GPpJh/1/)